# Powerapps or spfx to built forms in SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, powerapp

I need to create a few forms on SharePoint online, but first I would like to know which one to use PowerApps or SPFx?

Can I use workflow on powerapps or spfx?

**Edit:**
the complexity of the form is like this:
These forms are not bound to a particular list or library. The form will contain different tabs, thus different views. Depending on the status of the workflow, a different view (tab) will be enabled.

Later some graphs can be added.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPFx is coding with TypeScript, HTML, CSS, etc. If you're not comfortable with those, and if you don't have between 6 months - 3 years to ramp up on them, go with PowerApps.

Yes, powerapps can support different screens or forms being visible based on a condition. By "workflow", you'll just need to have a field available to indicate what the current workflow state is.

Comment: can powerapps send an email and can I create the form in a page, not bound to a list or library?

Comment: Yes, you can send an email from powerapps or from the workflow (flow). Yes, you can create a form that connects to multiple lists, or no lists. The form doesn't get "created" in a page, but gets created as a standalone app, and then can be added to any page. Here's a video from Shane for sending an email: https://youtu.be/bF7WkqtxKB0

Answer (score 1):

This is totally depend on the complexity of your list form.

I would suggest you to use PowerApps for creating new form on a list as:

1. It can be opened directly from list view.
2. You can easily connect to multiple data sources in powerapps.
3. You can do complex calculations, disable/hide form fields based on some conditions, cascade drop-downs if you need.
4. Also you can run **Microsoft flow** from PowerApps. For example, [Call Microsoft Flow from PowerApps](https://www.google.com/amp/s/piyushksingh.com/2018/11/07/call-microsoft-flow-from-powerapps/amp/).

Comment: thank you for your reply. The form is not bound to a particular list or library. The form will contain different tabs, and even graphs may be added later

Comment: If you want to use PowerApps then you can create an App with multiple screens/tabs as you want it. You can also add graphs.. Gallery... DataTables in app very easily with less code.

Comment: Also, as I already mentioned it is totally depend on the complexity of all your requirements. If the form data calculations are complex, calculations for graphs are complex and you are comfortable with coding then you can use SPFx as well.

Comment: Does this answers your question? Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.